# Rebuild window function row_number in sybase

Tags: sybase, window-functions

I have a problem that I could easily solve if I had window functions available in Sybase, but I dont:

Consider a table `test`:

```
+------------+----------------+-------------+
| Account_Id | Transaction_Id | CaptureDate |
+------------+----------------+-------------+
| 1          | 1              | 2014-01-01  |
| 1          | 2              | 2013-12-31  |
| 1          | 3              | 2015-07-20  |
| 2          | 1              | 2012-02-20  |
| 2          | 2              | 2010-01-10  |
| ...        | ...            | ...         |
+------------+----------------+-------------+
```

I want to get a result set containing for each Account The most recent `CaptureDate` with the corresponding `Transaction_Id`. With the window function `row_number` this would be easy:

```
select Accounts_Id, CaptureDate, Transaction_Id from 
    (select 
    CallAccounts_Id,
    CaptureDate,
    Transaction_Id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by Accounts_Id order by CaptureDate desc) row
    from test) tbl
where tbl.row = 1
```

but my sybase version does not have this. Obviously, sth like

```
select max(Transaction_Id ), max(Transaction_Id ), Account_Id 
from test
group by Account_Id
```

does not work because it does not always give me the correct Transaction_Id.
How can I do this then in Sybase and not make it terribly verbose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
SELECT  Account_Id, Transaction_Id, CaptureDate
FROM    test a
WHERE   CaptureDate =   (
                        SELECT  MAX(CaptureDate)
                        FROM    test b
                        WHERE   a.Account_Id = b.Account_Id
                    )
```

EDIT 1:
Duplicate CaptureDate was not in your example, so I did not take care of that scenario. Try below:

```
SELECT  Account_Id, Transaction_Id, CaptureDate
FROM    test a
WHERE   CaptureDate =   (
                        SELECT  MAX(CaptureDate)
                        FROM    test b
                        WHERE   a.Account_Id = b.Account_Id
                    )
AND     Transaction_Id =
                    (
                        SELECT  MAX(Transaction_Id)
                        FROM    test c
                        WHERE   a.Account_Id  = c.Account_Id
                        AND     a.CaptureDate = c.CaptureDate
                    )
```

Comment: Ok Thanks! But how to deal with identical CaptureDate (Take higher Transaction_Id in this case)? I only want one result row for this case